# Convert string values to list python

Tags: python, list, string-conversion

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to take a string in a line from a file that is being read using readline(). Specifically, there are multiple integer values which is where I am running into issues:

```
10 20 30
```

I would like the values above to be converted into a list of separate integers:

```
[10, 20, 30]
```

The values would then be summed within a separate class. I'm certain there is something simple I could do here, but I'm just drawing a blank. Thanks in advance!

Here's more context as to what I am trying to do. I'm passing the integers into an updateMany method in my class:

```
vals = infile.readline() 
a.updateMany(int(vals.split())
```

updateMany() takes the list and sums them, adding them to a list variable local to the class.

Comment: Show us what you tried and add some more examples.

Comment: Sorry - added more to the above. TY!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
thelist = [int(s) for s in thestring.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
x = [int(i) for i in "10 20 30".split()]
```

then

```
sum(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You van use `map()`. It takes items from a list and applies given function upon them.

```
>>> string = "10 20 30"
>>> map(int, string.split())
[10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use space as separator, you can use split method of a string object:

```
>>> num_line = '10 20 30'
>>> [int(num) for num in num_line.split() if num]
[10, 20, 30]
```

If your separator is more than one char like ',' and '.' or space, you can use re.split():

```
>>> import re
>>> re_str = "[,. ]"
>>> num_line = '10, 20, 30.'
>>> [int(num) for num in re.split(re_str, num_line) if num]
[10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help and different ways of solving this. I ended up using the following to get my values:

```
intList = [int(i) for i in vals.split(sep=' ')]
a.updateMany(intList)
```

Cheers!